# Flume. Line deserializer adds unicode symbols to loglines in Kafka channel

Tags: unicode, apache-kafka, flume

I am using flume with following config for parsing nginx logs and put them into kafka.

```
#define sources, channels and sink
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c2

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /spool/upload_flume
a1.sources.r1.fileSuffix = .DONE
a1.sources.r1.basenameHeader = false
a1.sources.r1.fileHeader = false
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 1000
a1.sources.r1.deserializer.maxLineLength = 11000
a1.sources.r1.decodeErrorPolicy = IGNORE
a1.sources.r1.deserializer.outputCharset = UTF-8

#define channels
a1.channels.c2.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
a1.channels.c2.brokerList=kafka10:9092,kafka11:9092,kafka12:9092
a1.channels.c2.topic = test001_logs
a1.channels.c2.zookeeperConnect = kafka10:2181,kafka11:2181,kafka12:2181
a1.channels.c2.parseAsFlumeEvent = true

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c2
```

For some reason In resulting entries in kafka topic there are unicode symbols appended to loglines. For example:

```
\00\F4176.124.146.227   1469439200.715 ...
\00\DE185.18.5.6    1469439200.715  3146510 ... 
\00\B0176.15.87.26  1469439200.717  80674 ...
```

Why this happens and how to avoid such problem?

Thanks in advance!

Update.
If I use kafka as a **sink** for memory channel with the same 'spoolDir' settings - there are no any unicode additions in resulted entries in kafka topic. But this way doesn't looks like right solution, because I have to use additional resources for memory channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    *`a1.channels.c2.parseAsFlumeEvent = false`*